# How can I invoke an angular service from a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have an angular module with the following code:

```
angular.module('sampleModule', [])

.service('myService', [function () {
    this.showAlert = function () {
        alert("Hello");
    };

    this.sum = function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    };
}])

.controller('SampleCtrl', ['myService', '$scope', function ($scope, myService) {
    this.doSum = function () {
        var result = myService.sum(1, 2);
        alert(result);
    };
}]);
```

When I invoke doSum I get:

**TypeError: myService.sum is not a function**

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller DI is wrong- note the order of the arguments:

```
.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    this.doSum = function () {
        var result = myService.sum(1, 2);
        alert(result);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I suspect the order matters because 'myService' depends on '$scope', so myService has to come after the required $scope. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Issue with sequencing of injections are not proper. $scope should come before myService.

```
Correct code:
.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    this.doSum = function () {
        var result = myService.sum(1, 2);
        alert(result);
    };
}]);
```